# Why do I keep getting this "help" error code from Wikipedia API?

Tags: ruby, mediawiki

I'm trying to get a random page from Wikipedia, using [WikiMedia's documented Random method](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery_-_Lists#random_.2F_rn).

Safari has no problem getting the page: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=random&rnlimit=1&rnnamespace=0&format=json

But when I do, using Ruby HTTP/Net, I keep getting this exact error page: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php (with the same "help" error code, and empty info).

```
url = URI.parse('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=random&rnlimit=1&rnnamespace=0&format=json')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path, "User-Agent" => "ourbandiscalled")
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http| http.request(req)}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Thank you,

Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`url.path` only returns `"/w/api.php"` so you are losing the query string from your URL in the GET request. You can use `url.request_uri` instead e.g.

```
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.request_uri, "User-Agent" => "ourbandiscalled")
```

The query string on its own is available as `url.query`. In summary:

```
irb(main):045:0> url.path
=> "/w/api.php"
irb(main):046:0> url.query
=> "action=query&list=random&rnlimit=1&rnnamespace=0&format=json"
irb(main):047:0> url.request_uri
=> "/w/api.php?action=query&list=random&rnlimit=1&rnnamespace=0&format=json"
```

Comment: Perfect! I don't know why I couldn't find it in the documentation. Thanks a lot, my mini-site is now available: http://ourbandiscalled.com :-)